# Where do neurons in a neural network share their predictive results (learned functions)?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

Definitely a noob NN question, but here it is:

I understand that neurons in a layer of a neural network all initialize with different (essentially random) input-feature weights as a means to vary their back-propagation results so they can converge to different functions describing the input data. However, I do not understand when or how these neurons generating unique functions to describe the input data "communicate" their results with each other, as is done in ensemble ML methods (e.g. by growing a forest of trees with randomized initial-decision criteria and then determining the most discriminative models in the forest). In the trees ensemble example, all of the trees are working together to generalize the rules each model learns.

How, where, and when do neurons communicate their prediction functions? I know individual neurons use gradient descent to converge to their respective functions, but they are unique since they started with unique weights. How do they communicate these differences? I imagine there's some subtle behavior in combining the neuronic results in the output layer where this communication is occurring. Also, is this communication part of the iterative training process?

Someone in the comments section (https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/14028/what-is-the-purpose-of-multiple-neurons-in-a-hidden-layer) asked a similar question, but I didn't see it answered.

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This does not seem to be a question about programming.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro If theory and applications of machine learning in programming are separated into different websites (which I don't think), please direct me to the nn-programming theory website. Otherwise, I'm quite sure this question is about programming. I'm only asking this question to understand how to implement an nn.

Comment: Sure, look here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During propagation, each neuron typically participates in forming the value in multiple neurons of the next layer. In back-propagation, each of those next-layer neurons will try to push the participating neurons' weights around in order to minimise the error. That's pretty much it.

For example, let's say you're trying to get a NN to recognise digits. Let's say that one neuron in a hidden layer starts getting ideas on recognising vertical lines, another starts finding horisontal lines, and so on. The next-layer neuron that is responsible for finding `1` will see that if it wants to be more accurate, it should pay lots of attention to the vertical line guy; and also the more the horisontal line guy yells the more it's *not* a `1`. That's what weights are: telling each neuron how strongly it should care about each of its inputs. In turn, the vertical line guy will learn how to recognise vertical lines better, by adjusting weights for its input layer (e.g. individual pixels).

(This is quite abstract though. No-one told the vertical line guy that he should be recognising vertical lines. Different neurons just train for different things, and by the virtue of mathematics involved, they end up picking different features. One of them might or might not end up being vertical line.)

There is no "communication" between neurons on the same layer (in the base case, where layers flow linearly from one to the next). It's all about neurons on one layer getting better at predicting features that the next layer finds useful.

At the output layer, the `1` guy might be saying "I'm 72% certain it's a `1`", while the `7` guy might be saying "I give that `7` a B+", while the third one might be saying "A horrible `3`, wouldn't look at twice". We instead usually either take whoever's loudest's word for it, or we normalise the output layer (divide by the sum of all outputs) so that we have actual comparable probabilities. However, this normalisation is not actually a part of neural network itself.